# Cassandra write propagation to remote DCs

Tags: cassandra

When a write to Cassandra uses LOCAL_QUORUM, is the coordinator node at the originating DC the sole propagator to the remote DCs, or can other nodes/DCs share that role if, say, something happens to the coordinator or to its connectivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a write query is submitted to Cassandra, independently of its consistency level, the local coordinator receiving the request will **select a remote coordinator** in each of the other datacenters to forward the write to. Thus each datacenter will handle the replication of the mutation independently after receiving it from the original coordinator.

If the local coordinator becomes unavailable before forwarding the request to other datacenters, Cassandra doesn't have a mechanism to replace it, and that sort of failure is usually handled by drivers via query retries. If the inter-dc writes fail due to connectivity issues, the failed mutations will be stored in the coordinator in the form of hints, to be replayed once the connectivity issues are resolved.

I haven't tested specifically for multiple datacenters, but the only odd scenario where where I think this may not be true is when using logged batches.
When a logged batch is used, 2 non-coordinator replicas store a copy of the batchlog for replay in case the coordinator fails. In some ways, these replicas act as failover coordinators, and I believe they replay the batchlog to replicas in different datacenters, but haven't yet tested it.

Either way, I want to be clear: that's not a good enough reason for using logged batches. The overhead on coordinators can be a showstopper, specially when upserting to multiple partitions.

Comment: @M%c3%a1rioTavares It sounds like in the case of a lost originating coordinator forwarding a LOCAL_QUORUM write, some sort of repair followup would be needed.  Are Reaper sidecars able to handle this, if the write has been propagated to at least one other remote DC?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of this, but you can specify which datacenters you want to run/schedule a repair for in the Cassandra-Reaper UI in the `Datacenters` field. To confirm that data is synced across datacenters in a given repair run, in the Reaper webui check the details of run and select a token segment. There you should see which nodes were repaired for it. If you only see 3 (assuming replication factor 3 per DC) that means that repairs are intra-DC, and you need to change the schedule settings to repair inter-DC.

Comment: However, inter-dc repairs may get expensive once streaming is involved. The scenario you're concerned about, although not impossible, is highly unlikely. Therefore I'm not sure it's worth paying the networking overhead cost to mitigate a problem that is likely to never manifest.